# Postgres Full Text Search on multiple columns

Tags: postgresql, laravel, postgresql-9.3, laravel-5

I am using Postgres 9.3 w/ Laravel 5 and I have set up the following migration:

```
DB::statement("ALTER TABLE users ADD COLUMN searchtext TSVECTOR");
DB::statement("UPDATE users SET searchtext = to_tsvector('english', first_name || ' ' || last_name || ' ' || email)");
DB::statement("CREATE INDEX searchtext_gin ON users USING GIN(searchtext)");
DB::statement("CREATE TRIGGER ts_searchtext BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON users FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE tsvector_update_trigger('searchtext', 'pg_catalog.english', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email')");
```

If I have an entry with the first name "Christopher", and I run the following query I get no results

```
return User::whereRaw("searchtext @@ to_tsquery('Chris')")->get();
```

If I search for "Christopher" I get the record. What do I need to do to be able to search with a partial match?

Answer (score 1):

The `english` dictionary doesn't stem nicknames.

```
regress=> SELECT to_tsvector('english', 'Christopher'), to_tsquery('english', 'Chris');
  to_tsvector  | to_tsquery 
---------------+------------
 'christoph':1 | 'chris'
(1 row)
```

You'll need to overlay a dictionary that maps nicknames too, so `christopher` can be stemmed to `chris`.